# Fixing DBus after changing /home /lib and /root permissions

Tags: d-bus, firewalld, alma-linux

Firstly, **I know, it was dumb, but now it's done and don't need to say "why did you do that" etc...**

So, I'm using Almalinux 9 and I changed permissions of /home /lib and /root. Now, firewalld fail to start and so does dbus-broker. I can not connect through ssh even though sshd is running. I don't know what to look for and what to fix

Here is part of the displayed errors :

```
[FAILED] Failed to start D-Bus System Message Bus.

...

dbus-broker.service
Active : failed

...

main @ ../src/launch/main.c + 170
Exiting due to fatal error -107
...
systemd[1]: failed to start D-Bus System Message Bus.
```

Of course i could just reinstall my system, but it would be way better to just, fix it even if it's temporary.

Have a good day

Comment: You changed the permissions - did you change then back, already? And reinstalling the system might, by far, be the quickest solution here, so don't rule that out.

Comment: Well, quickest except that i can't access the physical machine until friday night so it might not be the quickest quickest and i would love to at least, fix it and reinstall it this friday. I've tried to change everything back to 777 (i know its bad but i don't have anything to lose)

Comment: that is actively worse. Now you don't even have permission information anymore. Trying to change everything back will be quite a futile and probably lengthy endeavour, so, yeah, reinstall. Everything else is just not feasible.

Comment: Alright, thanks, at least I know I can't do anything and well, my mistake I won't start again.

Comment: You have stirred your system with a `root` stick. There are dozens of carefully selected permission  values in use on those filesystems, and you have set them all to the same value. You broke your system. Reinstall. This is an XY problem, so you should ask yourself "Why did I do that?" and, after you reinstall, ask a differrent Question.